# redirecting in node.js behind Apache mod_rewrite proxy

Tags: apache, node.js, mod-rewrite

I have a node.js application running behind an Apache mod_rewrite proxy configured in a .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mydomain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:3000/$1 [QSA,P]
```

When I now do a redirect (e.g. express' `res.redirect()`) inside my node.js application (which runs on port 3000), the user is always redirected to `http://localhost:3000/` (which is in fact exactly what is defined above but not the desired behaviour).

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to the problem already?